# how to grant non-admin users the right to assign users to a queue

Tags: community, administration

would like to know if   Is there a way we can provide a Manage Queue type permission without managing users' permissions?

Comment: Did you check the workaround provided here in this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpBdAAK)?

Comment: is there any other way without Delegated Aminstration?